# How to add InPost widget to your site?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add Inpost widget to my site, which is written in pure html. When I add mapWidget, everything works fine, but when I try to add dropdownWidget, chrome console shows error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: dropdownWidget is not defined
    at Object.e.dropdownWidget (sdk-for-javascript.js:1)
    at window.onload (1.html:16)

My code:

```
<script async src="https://sandbox-geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://sandbox-geowidget.easypack24.net/css/easypack.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.easyPackAsyncInit = function () {
        easyPack.init({});
        window.onload = function() {
            easyPack.dropdownWidget('easypack-widget', function(point) {
    console.log(point)
            });
        }
    };
</script>
<div id="easypack-widget"></div>
```

I found documentation at this address: https://docs.inpost24.com/display/PL/%5B4.5.0%5D+Geowidget+Documentation

Comment: Is that your full code?

Comment: I think you need to contact them a their javascript seems broken.

Comment: I do think so too, but I wanted to get another opinion. For example, code with mapWidget works good.